# No shows me the number on console

Tags: assembly, console, numbers, show

I have the following code in assembler:

What happens is that does not show me anything in console, I want you to show me the final number.

```
section .text
global _start
_start:

inicio:     
    mov ax,12345
    mov cx,5
    mov dx,0
imprime:
    mov bx,10
    div bx
    add dl,30h
    mov dh,0
    push dx
    mov dx,0

    loop imprime 
    mov cx,5
    imp:    
        mov ah,02h
        pop dx 
        int 0x80
        loop imp

mov rax, 60
mov rdi, 0
syscall
```

I put the int 21h to print it and did not leave me, I changed int 0x80

Comment: platform? (OS + bits). `int 21h` is MS-DOS, `int 0x80` is 32b linux, `syscall` is 64b linux (or any other OS using it too). You can't call API of other OS, stick with yours. (and each API has it's own functions and parameters... so `mov ah,02h` together with `int 0x80` is almost certainly bug, linux 32b API expect value in `eax`).

Comment: @Ped7g i use ubuntu 64 bits linux and yasm, but if i use syscall make mistake

Comment: @Ped7g if i put syscall, comes out: "Violation segment ('core' generated)"

Comment: When I use syscall, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning, this answer will not help you, what you need is to get some debugger and learn to use it (**gdb** is almost everywhere in *NIX, so learning it once will server you well. I can't remember anything, so I use some GUI stuff, which almost always has some bugs, but "edb" is OK for this small asm stuff for me).

Here is somewhat fixed linux 64b assembly code of yours, which works for me:

```
; Kate build command (%f = file name, %n = name without extension):
; nasm -f elf64 -l %n.lst %f; ld -melf_x86_64 -o %n %n.o

section .data
    char_buffer db '_'  ; buffer to store characters to print

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    xor ecx,ecx     ; clear rcx! LOOP in 64b doesn't use only "cx"

    ; store 5 ASCII chars on stack (decimal format of value in ax)
    mov ax,12345
    mov cx,5
    mov dx,0
imprime:
    mov bx,10
    div bx
    add dl,30h
    mov dh,0
    push dx
    mov dx,0
    loop imprime 

    ; print 5 stored ASCII chars on stack
    mov cx,5
    mov rdi,1           ; stdout
    mov rsi,char_buffer ; memory buffer for number
imp:    
    pop dx
    mov [rsi],dl        ; update number in buffer
    mov rax, 1          ; sys_write
    mov rdx, 1          ; 1 byte length
    push rcx            ; rcx is not preserved by syscall
    syscall
    pop rcx             ; restore rcx for LOOP
    loop imp

    ; print new line
    mov [rsi],byte 10   ; NL char into buffer
    mov rax,1           ; sys_write
    ; other arguments are valid from previous call
    syscall

    ; sys_exit
    mov rax,60
    mov rdi,0
    syscall
```